# Python How to split string only if value post selected delimiter is a number?

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to split a string using lib re, and I need to split the values using some delimiters, but for one specific I'm having a little trouble. The problem is i need to split just if the next character following the space is a number.
For example

```
import re
a = 'Trying de one'
b = 'Trying de 10'
a = re.split('ate |de |do ',a)[0]
b = re.split('ate |de |do ',b)[0]
```

What i need is the output to be:

```
a = 'Trying de one'
b = 'Trying de '
```

And i'm just getting the second one every time.

Comment: Do you want a split or substitution?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture either `ate` `de` or `do` followed by a space that you want to keep, and match 1 or more digits that you want to remove.

In the replacement use capture group 1.

```
import re

pattern = r"\b(ate |d[eo] )\d+";

a = 'Trying de one'
b = 'Trying de 10'

a = re.sub(pattern, r'\1', a)
b = re.sub(pattern, r'\1', b)

print(a)
print(b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/igeDF5/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VgpgGH)

Output

```
Trying de one
Trying de
```

---

If you have to use split, one option is to make use of lookarounds, asserting either `ate`  `de`  or `do`  on the left and a digit on the right.

```
import re

pattern = r"(?:(?<=ate )|(?<=d[eo] ))(?=\d)"

a = 'Trying de one'
b = 'Trying de 10'

a = re.split(pattern, a)
b = re.split(pattern, b)
print(a[0])
print(b[0])
```

Output

```
Trying de one
Trying de
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H705VR/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/0oNP7b)